# Generating table of contents for multi-file asciidoc book

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I am a beginner at asciidoc. I have structured my project into modular files so it is easier to manage. And I am able to generate the pdf using asciidoctor. However, the toc does not include the list of files it gets through the `include` directive.

Here is the main file:

```
= Booktitle
Vinay <email>
:sectnums:
:toc:
:toclevels:

:leveloffset: 1

include::chapters/chapter_00.adoc
include::chapters/chapter_01.adoc
include::chapters/chapter_02.adoc

:leveloffset: 0
Index
======
```

And here is chapter_01.adoc:

```
= The First Chapter

This is the first chapter.
```

The table of contents only includes a link to the Index. What am I doing wrong?

The command I used is: `asciidoctor-pdf book.adoc`

Answer (score 2):

Your include is missing a pair of square brackets. For a book that has a title page, you might want to set the `doctype` attribute to `book`. The attribute `toclevel` should be set to a number indicating the heading levels you want to list in your table of contents. If you leave it empty, the table of contents will be empty.

Tested with Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.3 using Asciidoctor 2.0.10, the following worked for me:

```
= Booktitle
Vinay <email>
:sectnums:
:toc:
:toclevels: 2
:doctype: book

:leveloffset: 1

include::chapters/chapter_00.adoc[]
include::chapters/chapter_01.adoc[]
include::chapters/chapter_02.adoc[]

:leveloffset: 0

[Index]
= Index
```

Comment: It seems `[index]` (lowercase) must be used, in order for the index to work.